# Will GCM works on Android 4.0 upgraded from Android 2.1

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-2.0-eclair

I am having GCM push notification in my project. I know GCM will work for Android 2.2 and above. But will it work for those phone having Android 4.0 which were upgraded from Android 2.1 ?

Comment: There was a phone upgraded from 2.1 to 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using GCM on both Android version.

It works fine, the compatibility problems are only about actual version, and not about the olders, and in this case, with the 4.0, it's all fine.

Comment: You mean 4.0(ICS) upgraded from 2.1(Eclair) ? /n GCM on both Android version ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using my app on my DHD which was an old android 2.2 and now is a 4.0.1 rooted device.

Comment: That is fine because 2.2 and 4.0 supports GCM. But Android 2.1 didn't. So if one upgrade from 2.1 to 4.0, Will GCM works ?